# Multiple nodes in a Single elastic server

Tags: elasticsearch

I am seeing multiple nodes in a single elastic server.

where I had specified to be only one.

this server is used to parse logstash logs

[image]

Comment: try to use the API `http://localhost:9200/_nodes` to see the other nodes

Comment: It seems like you have 3 Elasticsearch servers running with only one designated as a data node (the other two are probably [client nodes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/modules-node.html)). Also, because only data nodes can hold data, your cluster is in yellow state meaning that the replicas of your indexes cannot be stored anywhere (see `unassigned_shards`). You should find out why the other two nodes have `data: false` and probably change that setting.

Comment: If you are querying against this server already, you may have you client connecting as another Node through the API, which will join the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have connected the logstash instances with transport client. As you can see there is only one data node in the screenshot. THis way logstash instances connects to the cluster as a elastic node, but do not get index requests because they are set as data and master false.